# 20% discount for if statement oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some oracle sql code, I am trying to apply a 20% discount when product quantity is greater than 50 but am struggling with what approach to take, I also have a check to ensure that otherwise the total cost equals product quantity * unit cost. What approach would you suggest?

Comment: why do you want to do this in the database? This seems like the sort if thing I'd put in my application logic

Comment: The approach I would first take would be to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]).  What does your table look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @Azsgy - If you have a lot of products and a lot of customers, you would do much, much better to do the computation "in the database" and not "in the application."

Answer (score 2):

There are no "if" statements in SQL, but there are `case` expressions. Something like this:

```
select .....,
       quantity * unit_cost * case when quantity > 50 then 0.8 else 1 end as total_cost
from   .....
where  .....    (etc.)
```

The `case` expression (from the word `case` to the word `end`, inclusive) evaluates to 0.8 when the quantity is greater than 50 (this is the same as applying a 20% discount: the customer pays only 80% of what they would pay otherwise). If the quantity is less than or equal to 50, then you multiply quantity times unit cost (times 1, which is the same as ignoring the last multiplication).